# MYSQL Like query only the keyword matchcase

Tags: php, mysql

We have designed a database but there was a bug in design and we are in big issue now, may be like query in any way help us out.

In my locations table of my database, I have some record's like this:

```
E2
W3,SE2,SW13,E2
SE2
W3,E2
W3,SE2
```

Now I want to fetch all the results that contains `E2`. If I use `like` it also gets `SE2`, and I don't want that.

**Basically**, I want to find `E2` even if it's in a row that has other values separated by `,`.

If i search for `SE2` then I don't want to get `E2` as result, even if it's in a row that has other values separated by `,`.

**Basically**, I want to find `SE2` even if it's in a row that has other values separated by `,`.

Comment: @FirstOne actually the data is stored with comma sepration if i use that query it doesn't work's with comma sepration

Comment: @FirstOne i understand but i am working with my data with comma sepration

Comment: @FirstOne Yes that's what i want thanks for understanding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For records stored as comma-separated values, you're better off using [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('E2', your_column) > 0;
```

Comment: it work's can you help me how to run this query in php!

Comment: It is best to ask a new question for that. I suggest having a go first (the syntax is no different from a normal LIKE query) - and then ask if you get stuck! Please include what you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with some or condition

```
select * from my_table 
where my_column = 'E2' 
or my_column like '%,E2'
or my_column like 'E2,%'
```

for SE2 the query is

```
select * from my_table 
where my_column = 'SE2' 
or my_column like '%,SE2'
or my_column like 'SE2,%' 
or my_column like '%,SE2,%'
```

or generally

```
select * from my_table 
where my_column = 'your_key' 
or my_column like '%,your_key'
or my_column like 'your_key,%' 
or my_column like '%,your_key,%'
```

Comment: What about if i search for SE2 i have a huge database i just want to find the exact word for example if in the first record i have E2 and second record i have W3,SE2,SW13,E2 and third record i have SE2 then it should find the second and third record because it match SE2

Comment: 5 minutes are for comments  .. is not possible edit a comment after 5 minutes .. .. the answer could be edited without this limit .. and for the new  .. edit is possible editing the answer every time I want

Comment: Tell me the row that is not select based on your new sample and Be sure you don't have extra char in the fields ..

Comment: @scaisEdge i want to make it a general query

Comment: I have added the last (hope condition)  ... for the general l query ... is necessary find the correct situation .. i think shoulld be these 4